# python +expect+ truecrypt - не создает файл

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

Доброе утро.

В общем есть скрипт на bash, который успешно создает нужный мне контейнер,
вот его код:

```
#!/bin/bash

starttime=$(date +%s)
#truecrypt
type=1 #Тип Нормальный или скрытый
filesize=10M # Размер контейнера
encrypt=6 # Тип шифрования Serpent-AES
hash=1 # Тип хеша RIPEMD-160
fs=2 #тип файловаой системы, нам FAT подойдет под Windows
l320=`pwgen -s 320 1`
pass_tcp=`pwgen -s 64 1`
PATHLOCAL="/etc/maket"
PATHUSB="$PATHLOCAL/soft_usb"
keyfile="$PATHUSB/!!/key.txt"
startbat="$PATHUSB/open.bat"
tcp="waw"

#create truecrypt container

if ! [ -d $PATHUSB ]; then
    echo 'Папки нет - создание папки '$PATHLOCAL
    mkdir -p -v $PATHLOCAL/{apps,soft_usb,mnt}
    mkdir -p -v $PATHUSB/{!!,}
fi

echo `pwgen -s 30 6` > $keyfile

expect <<EOF
spawn /usr/bin/truecrypt -c $PATHUSB/!!/$tcp
expect true:
send "$type\n"
expect size:
send "$filesize\n"
expect ecrypt:
send "$encrypt\n"
expect Hash:
send "$hash\n"
expect filesystem:
send "$fs\n"
expect pass1:
send "$pass_tcp\n"
send "$pass_tcp\n"
expect filekey:
send $keyfile\n
expect finishkey:
send \n
expect L320:
send $l320\n

expect
EOF

expect <<EOF
spawn /usr/bin/truecrypt --keyfiles=$keyfile $PATHUSB/!!/$tcp     $PATHLOCAL/mnt
expect pass:
send "$pass_tcp\n"
expect secure:
send \n
expect
EOF

truecrypt -d

endtime=$(date +%s)
totaltime=$(( $endtime - $starttime ))
echo "Время выполнения скрипта: "$totaltime" секунд"
```

Это кусок кода прекрасно работает.

Пишу  его же на python'e. вот его код:

```
# -*- coding: utf -*-
import os,sys
import pexpect
import random
import string
import time

def random_id(n):
    rid = ''
    for x in range(n): rid += random.choice(string.ascii_letters +     string.digits)
    return rid
t1=time.time()
print(t1)

pass_tcp=random_id(64)

path='/home/firefedot/bash'
type='1' 
filesize='10M' 
encrypt='6' 
hash='1' 
fs='2' 
l320=random_id(320)
PATHLOCAL=path
PATHUSB=PATHLOCAL+"/soft_usb"
keyfile=PATHUSB+"/!!/readme.txt"
startbat=PATHUSB+"/start.bat"
tcp="waw"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("truecrypt")
    print(l320)
    f = open(keyfile, 'w')
    f.write(random_id(180)+'\n')
    f.close()
    os.chdir(path)
    k=pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/truecrypt -c '+PATHUSB+'/!!/'+tcp)
    #k.expect ("Volume type:")
    k.sendline(type)
    #k.expect ("size:")
    k.sendline(filesize)
    #k.expect ("ecrypt:")
    k.sendline(encrypt)
    #k.expect ("Hash:")
    k.sendline(hash)
    #k.expect ("filesystem:")
    k.sendline(fs)
    #k.expect ("pass1:")
    k.sendline(pass_tcp)
    k.sendline(pass_tcp)
    #k.expect ("filekey:")
    k.sendline(keyfile)
    #k.expect ("finishkey:")
    k.sendline('\n')
    #k.expect ("L320:")
    k.sendline(l320)
    k.close()

    o=pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/truecrypt --keyfiles='+keyfile+' '+PATHUSB+'/!!/'+tcp+' '+PATHLOCAL+'/mnt')
    #o.expect ("pass:")
    o.sendline (pass_tcp)
    #o.expect ("secure:")
    o.sendline ('\n')
    o.close()

    os.system('truecrypt -d')
    print(os.system('ls -lah '+PATHUSB+'/!!'))
    t2=time.time()
    print(t2-t1)
```

Суть такова, что скрипт создает контейнер,  затем его открывает, затем сует в него нужные файлы (в данном примере копирование опустил).

Проблема в том, что скрипт на питоне не создает файл контейнера.

А если k.sendline(l320) за менить на k.sendline(l320+'\n'), то создается файл 0кб. Так же, если переменную filesize='10M' заменить на filesize='10240' (думал может буква не нравится) - результат тот же.

Пробовал обойтись без переменных - не помогло.

Все #k.expect и #o.expect закоментированы по причине того, что питон ругается на них:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/firefedot/NetBeansProjects/truecrypt/src/truecrypt.py", line 47, in <module>
    k.expect ("Volume type:")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1418, in expect
timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1433, in expect_list
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1521, in expect_loop
    raise EOF(str(err) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7f469b990190>
version: 3.1
command: /usr/bin/truecrypt
args: ['/usr/bin/truecrypt', '-c', '/home/firefedot/bash/soft_usb/!!/waw']
searcher: <pexpect.searcher_re object at 0x7f469b990210>
buffer (last 100 chars): ''
before (last 100 chars): ''
after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 13912
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Хоть подобная конструкция отлично работает при создании файла keepass (p.expect).

В чем может быть проблема?

Хотел воспользоваться pdb  или ipdb,  но к сожалению пока не имею такой возможности.

Спасибо.

Comment: желательно [минимальный самодостаточный пример кода показывать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Потренируйтесь на скрипте-заглушке вместо truecrypt (просто `raw_input()`, `print()`, `time.sleep()` и создание файла с задержкой). Чтобы избежать исключения, нужно  `expect(pexpect.EOF)` вызвать.

Comment: Спасибо попробую, но проделал тоже самое на keepass  и openvpn  все без проблем сработало

Answer (score 1):

В общем спасибо за коментарий, добавил k.expect(pexpect.EOF); в конец работы pexect

и поправил переменные с

```
k=pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/truecrypt -c '+PATHUSB+'/!!/'+tcp)
```

на

```
k=pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/truecrypt -c %s' %tcp)
```

Все работает как надо. Спасибо.

И для сведения - на баше скрипт выполнятся за 145-152 секунд, а на питоне за 8-10 секунд, не зря старался.)